# CSS/HTML5 Responsive Header Image

Tags: css, html, image, responsive-design

I'd like my header image to scale with the browser size. 
This is my current code for the att. screen grab, but this doesn't scale the image on smaller screens. Ive tried using the background image options but this doesn't achieve the look I want.

```
  .header-image {    
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;   
    max-height:1000px;
    overflow:hidden;    
      left: 0; 
      right: 0;
    z-index:-1;         
      border:10px solid #545351;        
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top:50px;
    margin-top:-10px;       
}
```

& HTML

```
<div align="center"><!-- big image -->
        <div class="header-image"><img src="images/liveryHeader3.jpg"></div><!-- end of big image-->
</div><!-- end of center image class-->
```

[image: Screen Grab from current site]

[image: Example of what client sees]

The second image is roughly what shows on smaller monitor, the image hasn't scaled & layout looks odd - Id like to scale the horse head so that the full image still shows. It seems to work on Android & tablet, just not smaller monitors?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time interpreting your question. Are you asking how to have the background image scale vertically as well?

Comment: Please provide a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com) example.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good at posting questions here - 
No, Id like the image to appear as is (with overflow hidden) but to scale with the browser - the client has a smaller monitor & screen resolution than I do & the large image doesn't scale to show her its entirety?

Comment: Ive never used jsBin - sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this (It fits the size of the image so that it exactly covers the screen.):

```
.header-image img {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/leo/qsMKf/

Answer (score 1):

Your image won't scale down with width:100%; it will only scale up so whatever the size is of the image it will stay. You need to use a "media query" and then set a different % there.

Something like:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* put your specific styling here either replacing the background image with something smaller using % or sized down via % */
}
```

Comment: Im unsure of this? "replacing the background image with something smaller using % or sized down via % "

Comment: Meaning re-save the image at say, 50% smaller in width and call that in the css declaration so that 100% width will be smaller than what 100% of your current file is, or just keep the same image you have but specify a different % to 'place' it at. The idea is to load a smaller file. If you choose the other option, a smaller device will download the larger file then scale it down but it may not look as good as just actually saving down a smaller file.

Answer (score 1):

input the id into div like this (use only one div)

HTML:

```
<div id="header"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
  background-image:url(../images/liveryHeader3.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

OBS: into background-size, the first value is to width and second is to height

for more information : http://www.w3schools.com/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

code you provided doesn't scale image as it seen on screenshot, so you first should look at place where it is really stretched

anyway, check `max-height:1000px;` in css - this can limit, and of course you should add `width:100%;height:100%;` to your image and outer div as well

Comment: Not sure what you mean? code you provided doesn't scale image as it seen on screenshot Image is 2600 * 1405

Comment: @scotia I mean only this code will not scale image, there should be something more, maybe additional css or js

Answer (score 0):

If you put the actual image into the css as a background element and then set background-size to contain it should make it fit to the exact screen size.

something like this:

```
.header-image {    
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;   
    max-height:1000px;
    overflow:hidden;    
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    z-index:-1;         
    border:10px solid #545351;  
    background: url(*IMAGE URL HERE*) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

See how that goes.

Comment: Still no joy for me Rhys, is it perhaps my screen/resolution size that's making it "invisible" for me? (24" screen running 2560*1440)- I had tried the :cover; variant before with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand well what you really want.

You have to set max-width at 100% on your image and on it parent.

So your css for those element would look like this:

```
.header-image {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;   
    max-height:1000px;
    max-width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;    
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index:-1; /*places header image behind text */
    border:10px solid #545351;
}

.header-image img {
    max-width:100%; 
}
```

Comment: I understand your answer. My reason for max-height being 1000px (or approx. 80%) was to allow "more of the image" for larger screens like mine. I might have to simply shorten the image in order for it to scale traditionally. (rather than using less than 100% max-height with hidden overflow) & for the border property to remain 10px rather than an in-image border.